# How to use the result of previous row in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to compute the value of previous row to current row.

```
Col A | Col B

1     |   1     (A)

2     |   3    (A2+B1)

3     |   6    (A3+B2)
```

So the formula in column B is `A + (prev B)`

Is this possible in oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Analytical function and achieve this

```
create table tst (x number);
insert into tst values (1);
insert into tst values (2);
insert into tst values (3);
insert into tst values (4);
insert into tst values (5);

select x, sum(x) over (order by x) as y from tst;
```

Comment: THanks! You SAVE ME!