# How to sum all row per item?

Tags: sql, oracle

In relation to my previous question [How to use the result of previous row in oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51605118/how-to-use-the-result-of-previous-row-in-oracle#51605187)

I need to sum the value per item.

```
Col | Col A | Col B
Item1  1     |   1     (col A)
Item1  2     |   3     (colA + prevColB)
Item1  3     |   6     (colA + prevColB)
Item2  1     |   1     (colA)
Item2  4     |   5     (colA + prevColB)
Item2  3     |   8     (colA + prevColB)
```

Comment: . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as a "previous" row, unless a column specifies the ordering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Your cumulative sum assumes an ordering of the table, that is not apparent in the question.

The syntax for the cumulative sum is:

```
select t.*
       sum(cola) over (partition by col order by ?) as colb
from t;
```

The `?` is for the column (or expression) that represents the ordering of the rows.

Answer (score 0):

col is item i thing, u can try bellow

```
select col, sum(col A), sum( col B) from tb group by col
```

enjoy it broh

Answer (score 0):

If you mean Just one previous row value(but not overall sum), then use `lag` function ,which gives the value of the column for the previous row, as in the following *SQL* :

```
  select colA, colA+ 
     lag(colA,1,0) over (partition by Col order by Col ) as ColB
    from tab;

  COLA  COLB
    1     1
    2     3
    3     5
    1     1
    4     5
    3     7
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0dbdbf/2)